# how to find the maximum of the cross-entropy of a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, entropy

For a discrete random variable $x$, the cross entropy is
$$H(x) = -(p_1\log p_1+\cdots+p_n\log p_n),$$
so what is the maximum of $H(x)$?

Here is what I tried, I compute the gradient as follows
$$\nabla_pH = -\begin{pmatrix}\log p_1+1\\
\vdots\\ 
\log p_n+1\end{pmatrix},$$
and the Hessian matrix $\nabla_p^2H$ could also be computed, which is negative semi-definite, right? So $H(x)$ has one global maximum.

By setting $\nabla_pH = 0$, I could find out that the maximum is achieved at $p_i = 0.5$. However, since $\sum p_i = 1$, so this can't be true, how could I find when is the maximum is achieved in this case?

**UPDATE**

As @Semiclassical pointed out, I tried **Lagrangian multiplier**, here it is,
$$L(p_1,\cdots,p_n, \lambda) = H(x) + \lambda(\sum p_i - 1),$$
then set partial derivative of $L$ over $p_i$ to 0,
$$\nabla_{p_i}L = -\log p_i-1+\lambda = 0.$$
Thank to @Semiclassical, I indeed made a mistake not just a typo with the partial derivative over $p_i$, after fixing it, now I could solve the equation,
$$p_i = e^{\lambda-1},$$
so all the variables $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ shall have the same value to achieve maximum for $H(x)$, right?

Comment: You're trying to maximize a function in $n$ variables subject to a constraint. Lagrangian multipliers are an obvious suggestion (and, if you're doing entropy in the context of statistical mechanics, the multiplier has a physical meaning.)

Comment: @Semiclassical, yes I tried Lagrange multipliers, but failed to make sense of it, I'll update my post adding how I did it right away.

Comment: For the direct proof, use the fact that $x\mapsto x\ln x$ is convexe in $[0,1]$.

Comment: The maximum is achieved at $p_i=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You've got a typo in your last equation: You haven't differentiated $\sum p_i -1$ with respect to $p_i$.

Comment: @Hamou, yes, that's the answer, I'm trying to make sense of your kind hint: *$x\rightarrow x\ln x$ is convex in [0,1]*.

Comment: @Semiclassical, oops, you got me, ;-)

Comment: And that typo is really quite important, since if you correct it you can solve that equation for $p_i$. do that, and see what you can do with it.

Comment: @Semiclassical, updated.

Comment: Ding! And you know what they had up too, so you can finish. I'd suggest you write that up as an answer below.

Comment: @Semiclassical, thank you so much, I love stackexchane, ;P

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x\ln x$ is convex . $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^np_k\ln p_k=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}f(p_k)\geq nf(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^np_k) =-\ln n$ by Jensen inequality

Comment: +1, for the Jensen inequality, which makes me recall EM.